# How to install Intel's HAXM emulator on dual core processor machines?

Tags: android, emulation, haxm

Is there a solution how to install Intel's HAXM on machines with dual core processor? I tried to install it on my laptop, which has an Intel dual core processor. Is there a fix or solution?

Comment: If your laptop supports VT-x, yes, you can. And enable it in BIOS. If doesn't, you can't install the HAXM.

Comment: Exactly what platform and processor do you have? And what problems are you finding when trying to install HAXM? (And are you using the latest version, including checking for [hotfixes](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)?)

Comment: can you state your exact processor model number - then we can check ark.intel.com to see if it would support VT and ND bit

Answer (score 1):

To install Intel's HAXM, you need at least an Intel **Core 2 Duo** processor. It will not work with an Intel **Core Duo** since HAXM requires VT-x extensions, which aren't supported by Core Duo processors.

Also, some manufacturers shipped Core 2 Due processors with the VT-x extension disabled by default, so enter you BIOS configuration screen and make sure that the Virtualization/VT-x is enabled there. Here's an example of what the screen might look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Friend this is common problem,
please go to BIOS of your pc and **enable virtualisation option** and then again try to install it

that might help you